# RHL5 to Sunsolaries

Tags: unix

Below code works in bash but it is not working in ksh.
Presently i am using RHL5 version os below code is working fine but in sunsolaries it is not working.
In sunsolaries we are using Korn Shell.

```
#!/bin/bash
#give start date and enddate in the format yyyy_mm_dd
startdate="${1//_/-}"  # change underscores into dashes
enddate="${2//_/-}"
enddate=`date -d "$enddate + $i day" "+%Y_%m_%d"` #Increases enddate by 1 day so that        loop runs on given enddate also
enddate="${enddate//_/-}"
echo "StartDate: $startdate   EndDate+1Day: $enddate"
nextdate=$startdate #nextdate runs from startdate to enddate
while [ 1 ]
do
    echo "$nextdate $enddate"
if [ "$nextdate" == "$enddate" ];then     #after given enddate loop breaks
    break
fi
day=`date -d "$nextdate"`
arr=(${day// / })
echo "${arr[0]}"
if [ "${arr[0]}" == "Sat" ];then           #checking if day is Saturday, if true then increase nextday  and continue
    nextdate=`date -d "$nextdate + 1 day" "+%Y_%m_%d"`
    nextdate="${nextdate//_/-}"
    continue
fi
#####your code begins here
echo "creating file file_$nextdate.txt"
touch "file_$nextdate.txt" #test code, just creating files with date, remove this
#####your code ends here 
nextdate=`date -d "$nextdate + 1 day" "+%Y_%m_%d"`  #increasing nextday by 1 day
nextdate="${nextdate//_/-}"
done
```

Please help me how it works in ksh

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your script is using several time the Gnu date specific `-d` option. Either find a different way to achieve what it does in you use case, or install Gnu date on the Solaris machine if it isn't already.